# Docker CMD run bash script in background inside container

Tags: docker, containers

I'm trying to run script in background when the container creare (inside container).

I have the following simple `start.sh`:

```
f() {
    echo "Sleep"
    sleep 10
    echo "Done"
}

f
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alping
COPY start.sh /tmp
CMD /tmp/start.sh &
```

And after `docker run <MY_IMAGE>` the docker status is `Exited (0)`

I'm trying also to change start.sh to:

```
f() {
    echo "Sleep"
    sleep 10
    echo "Done"
}

f & #Run f function here in background
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alping
COPY start.sh /tmp
CMD /tmp/start.sh & # Trying also: CMD /bin/sh -c "/tmp/start.sh"
```

And got the same `Exited(0)` status.

So how can I run script in background when the container create?

Comment: What happens if you add a call to wait to the bottom of start.sh?

Comment: The container definitionally exits when its main _foreground_ process exits.  What’s that process?

Comment: @DavidMaze actually I need to start container, to wait 60seconds and then run my script inside the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you should be able to run your function in the background from within `start.sh`. if you don't call `wait`, then the container will exit (with the exit code of the foreground process) at the end of the script. If you *do* wait for the background function, you should see both statements printed to the container log before it completes.

It's usually best practice to have around one process per container, but definitely possible to have more, and there are good cases for applying that approach.

Comment: I'm running container with another application that not exit, I'm just trying to run my script while my application running

Comment: Yes, and that will work. Your example exits because nothing happens in the foreground. If you start a background process from a start script using `&` and then start the long running foreground process, both will run concurrently in the same container.

Comment: Ok, So I just try to add "sleep 15" after f & command  and its still exist with code 0

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "run in the background", there is no other command that will be running when you start the container.

If you want to start the container in the background, you do `docker run --detach`, but the `&` in the CMD is unnecessary.

Comment: I need to run my script in background when the container create I want my script.sh run in the background inside the container, wait 60 seconds (in sleep) and then start