# How to run a background process inside a child docker image in docker container

Tags: docker, shell, airflow

I'm trying to run a background process inside my airflow docker image, which will keep running to monitor some process and send an alert.

I have a parent image, which i'm using in my image say child image.
Here is the parent image docker file sample code snippet.

Parent Dockerfile:

```
FROM ${PYTHON_AIRFLOW_IMAGE} as my_img

#all other steps like copy/creating directory etc.

EXPOSE 8080 8443

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--", "/entrypoint"]
CMD []
```

Parent image tag

```
docker build -t parent_img .
```

My child image docker file, where i'm using parent image.

Child Image Dockerfile :

```
FROM parent_img:latest

USER root

COPY scripts/child_airflow.sh /child_airflow.sh

RUN bash /child_airflow.sh && rm /child_airflow.sh
    
COPY scripts/scheduler_health.sh scheduler_health.sh

COPY utils/health.py health.py

CMD ./scheduler_health.sh &
```

scheduler_health.sh will call the health.py file.

scheduler_health.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#This is a simple scheduler_health file to call health.py file

if [-e /scripts/health.py] then

echo "Scheduler Health, health.py file exist, hence calling"
 
python3 /scripts/health.py

else

echo "Scheduler health.py file doesn't exist"

fi
```

health.py file

```
import time
while True:
time.sleep(60)
sourceFile = open('/tmp/running.txt','a+')
print ('running, file=sourceFile)
```

child_airflow.sh file

```
source /bin/activate

pip install apache-airflow-providers-amazon apache-airflow-providers-celery -i

https://pypi.org/simple --no-cache-dir

bin/pip check
```

build child image :

```
docker build -t child .
```

run command :

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -it child
```

After running the child image, my health.py file is never called, looks like scheduler_health.sh not executing. even i tried calling scheduler_health.sh file inside child_airflow.sh too, but no luck no any error or no python file is executing ideally it should kept running in background and after 60 seconds it should write message to  /tmp/running.txt file.

Not sure if i'm missing anything , as per documentation https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ it should run, not sure if my parent entry point is overriding child process or i'm doing something wrong.

**Please note i can't modify anything on parent image , i mentioned parent docker file details here just for reference.**

I tried adding scheduler_health.sh & in child_airflow.sh also but not working

Comment: If your `CMD` only starts background processes, it will exit immediately; see for example [Docker CMD run bash script in background inside container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59759379/docker-cmd-run-bash-script-in-background-inside-container).  Your `CMD` should start the process in the foreground (I might skip the script and directly run `CMD ["./health.py"]`), but then you can `docker run -d` the _container_ in the background.

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks for your response, I need my `health.py` to run in background. once my container start actually it runs a process airflow scheduler from parent image, i want my health.py should also start and keep running in background, if you could suggest

Answer (score 2):

> I need my health.py to run in background

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78203542/how-to-run-a-background-process-inside-a-child-docker-image-in-docker-container#comment137873369_78203542), you need to make sure  the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#cmd) or [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#entrypoint) effectively manages *both* the Airflow scheduler and the `health.py` script without prematurely exiting.

That means the `entrypoint.sh` script must initiate both the Airflow scheduler (or the primary process started by the parent image's `ENTRYPOINT`) and the `health.py` script as background processes, and then waits indefinitely to keep the container running.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Start the health monitoring script in the background
./scheduler_health.sh &

# Start the main process in the background as well, if necessary
# Example: /start-airflow.sh &

# The original parent image's ENTRYPOINT is expected to start the airflow scheduler
# and potentially block. If it is just an initialization script and does not block,
# then you might need to start the scheduler manually here, similar to the commented-out line above.
exec /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /entrypoint "$@"
```

The `scheduler_health.sh` script should directly run `health.py` as intended.

When running your container, using [`docker run -d ...`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/run/#detach) ("detached mode") is recommended to make sure the container runs in the background.

Since `health.py` runs as a background process, make sure you have adequate logging in place to monitor its output and health status:  redirect its output to Docker's logging system (stdout/stderr) or to a file that can be accessed or tailed.

---

[Avatazjoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2008399/avatazjoe) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78203542/how-to-run-a-background-process-inside-a-child-docker-image-in-docker-container/78218894?noredirect=1#comment137957724_78218894):

> ...or you can try another approach ussing python subprocess modelule.

True, that is a good way to manage background processes within your Docker container, especially if you want to initiate and control these processes directly from Python. That should work for your scenario where you want `health.py` to run in the background alongside the main Airflow scheduler process.

You can create a wrapper Python script (`start_processes.py`) that starts both the Airflow scheduler (if needed) and the `health.py` script as subprocesses.
That script can use [Python's `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to start `health.py` as a background process and then proceeds to start or make sure the start of the Airflow scheduler process.

```py
import subprocess
import os

def run_in_background(command):
    """Run the given command as a background process."""
    return subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Start health.py as a background process
    run_in_background("python3 /health.py")
    
    # Example: Start another process here if necessary, e.g., a custom Airflow start script
    # run_in_background("bash /start-airflow.sh")
    
    # The last command should block to keep the script running
    # If the Airflow scheduler is started by the parent image's ENTRYPOINT, you might not need to start it manually.
    # If you do, make sure the last process started here is blocking, or use a wait loop to keep the script alive.
    os.system("tail -f /dev/null")
```

Adjust your Dockerfile to include this new wrapper script and set it as the command or entry point to execute when the container starts.

```
FROM parent_img:latest

USER root

# Copy necessary scripts and files
COPY scripts/child_airflow.sh /child_airflow.sh
COPY utils/health.py /health.py
COPY start_processes.py /start_processes.py

# Install any dependencies and run setup scripts
RUN bash /child_airflow.sh && rm /child_airflow.sh

# Set the Python wrapper as the entrypoint or CMD
CMD ["python3", "/start_processes.py"]
```

That would have the benefit of keeping all process management within a single Python script, making it potentially easier to manage, especially if you are already working within a Python-centric environment like Airflow.
And this approach can be more flexible if your processes need to communicate with each other or if their lifecycles are closely intertwined.

Using the `subprocess` module in this way allows for more sophisticated process management strategies, such as monitoring the output of background processes, restarting failed processes, or gracefully shutting down processes when the container is stopped.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i don't have control over the parent image i can't make any changes in parent if i can than it can be as simple as i can add this `scheduler_health.sh ` in parent entry point, but here i'm using parent image, i just shared parent details for reference. for child i have `child_airflow.sh`  but if i mentioned scheduler_health.sh in child it's not working so tried adding `CMD` in child docker file still no luck

Comment: @subodh But surely, you can make your own Docker image FROM the parent image? In that custom image, you can override/rewrite any script you want.

Comment: ...or you can try another approach ussing python subprocess modelule.

Comment: @Avatazjoe Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.